# error waiting for API Gateway Stage (ags-1suu2m3o7a-dev) to be available: unexpected state 'NOT_AVAILABLE', wanted target 'AVAILABLE'. last error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I use Terraform in order to create Api gateway stage, but when I try to set `cache_cluster_enabled = false` always I receive an error:

> error waiting for API Gateway Stage (ags-1suu2m3o7a-dev) to be
> available: unexpected state 'NOT_AVAILABLE', wanted target
> 'AVAILABLE'. last error: %!s()

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "example" {
  cache_cluster_enabled = false
  cache_cluster_size    = 0.5
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems for now you need to switch aws version to 3.73.0 according to this issue https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/22866 it will be fixed in future updates

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).